# Passing HWND through to a method and storing in a class

Tags: c++, winapi

I am calling the following:

```
// hMainWindow is a correctly functioning window handle
app.GetMainWindowInfo().SetHndToWindow( hMainWindow );
```

Here are my classes:

```
class App : public BaseClass
{
public:

    WindowInfo& GetMainWindowInfo();
    void SetMainWindowInfo( unique_ptr<WindowInfo> windowInfo );

private:

    WindowInfo mainWindowInfo;

};

class WindowInfo
{
public:

    HWND& GetHndToWindow() const;
    //void SetHndToWindow( HWND hndToWindow );

            // implementation on cpp file included here simply for example

            void WindowInfo::SetHndToWindow( HWND hndToWindow )
            {
                this->hndToWindow = hndToWindow;
            }

private:

    HWND hndToWindow; // Only for Windows OS

};
```

Now when i try and use the Getter method `GetHndToWindow`, I'm getting an unused back with unable to read memory.

Any ideas where i might be going wrong?

[image]

**Moving on from the above issue, in for example the app class, if i check the debugger at this line:**

[image]

My graphicContext class looks like this:

```
class IGraphicContext
{
    // Methods
public:

    virtual void Initialize() = 0;

private:

    // Properties

public:

    const WindowInfo& GetWindowInfo() const
    {
        return this->windowInfo;
    }

    void SetWindowInfo( WindowInfo& windowInfo )
    {
        this->windowInfo = windowInfo;
    }

protected:

    WindowInfo windowInfo;

};

class DXGraphicContext : public IGraphicContext, public BaseClass
{
    // Methods
public:

    DXGraphicContext();
    ~DXGraphicContext();

    virtual void Initialize() override;
   ...
```

Comment: What does the implementation of SendHndToWindow look like? Just seeing the declaration isn't enough, you need to provide the implementation. A HWND is a handle, so it should be fine to pass by value.

Comment: I've now included it in the code.

Comment: Unable to read memory isn't necessarily a problem, it just means that the debugger doesn't know how to read it for information. Have you tried just continuing on and ignore it?  

EDIT: I thought about it, seems like VS is trying to read the value as a pointer. My program gets the same thing for my HWND, so it should be good to go.

Comment: Window handles are opaque and the debugger normally doesn't have anything sensible to say about them.

Comment: Ahhh okay, now knowing that i can start to look. Thanks so much! Some of these debugger messages really get me!

Comment: I've added another few pictures to disdplay the real issue i'm having.. it seems when i go a bit deeper into my code the HWND is now null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IGraphicContext::SetWindowInfo` method makes a **copy** of the passed in `WindowInfo`. If the original is then modified later on (e.g. by calling `SetHndToWindow`) this won't affect the copy that `IGraphicContext` holds.

If you really want to share a structure like this between two separate classes you should look at holding it in a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I could just pass a refence to the handl to window in couldnt i

Comment: You're already passing a reference, but that's not enough, you'd need to **hold** a reference. And that has the potential to be unsafe - if the original object is destroyed before the thing holding a reference to it, you're left with a dangling pointer.